# Multiple key press detection wxPython 

Tags: python, tree, wxpython

I am creating a Project Manager using wxPython it has a splitter window. On one side is a tree that shows the names of and opens the files and on the other size is a textctrl that is used to edit the file.

One problem I am having is that I would like it to go back 4 spaces when SHIFT and TAB are pressed, I have code working that add's 4 spaces when TAB is pressed.

I am also have a problem that when I add a file that is in a different folder to my programs cwd the tree adds a new node and the file appears under this node and I am struggling to get the tree to save to a file.

Also I would like to know how to add an icon to an item in the tree from an external png file.

I would appreciate any help that could be given with either of these problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To catch multiple keys, you either need to catch EVT_CHAR or use an accelerator table. The latter is easier while the former may give you more control. Here are a couple tutorials for you:

- [wxPython: Catching Key and Char Events](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/08/29/wxpython-catching-key-and-char-events/)
- [wxPython: Keyboard Shortcuts (Accelerators)](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/12/02/wxpython-keyboard-shortcuts-accelerators/)

Comment: I've gotten the Keyboard Accelerators working but I don't know how to get it to go back 4 spaces like I have forward:                                                   `txt = ' ' * 4                                                            self.editor.WriteText(txt)`

Comment: I'm guessing it's something like myTxt.SetInsertionPoint(myTxt.GetInsertionPoint() - 4)

Comment: What do default python packages have to do with wxPython key presses?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know use WxPython and so don't have much idea about it. But in general what you can do is whenever a key is pressed, call a callback function and you could get the time when the key was pressed. save it somewhere. And when the next key is pressed, get the time. compare both times, if there's not much significant delay (you can decide the delay), it means that both the keys were pressed simultaneously (although they were not).

Comment: That's quite a good idea, is there not a current way to detect two buttons being pressed at once on python?

Comment: I haven't found any. And anyway, you can't press two buttons at once. The keyboard will send only one signal. So there will be a time delay.

Comment: I've gotten the Keyboard Accelerators working but I don't know how to get it to go back 4 spaces like I have forward: `txt = ' ' * 4 self.editor.WriteText(txt)`

Comment: okay. I am not getting what exactly you want to do. can you elaborate a bit ?

Comment: Like say in a program like Notepad ++ when you press the tab button it allows you to add 4 spaces in front of any text and to get text into alignment. But to go back 4 spaces incase I've gone too far with the text or something

Comment: If you can access your cursor (or file pointer/indexer) in wxpython, you can get the current position. Move back 4 positions. delete 4 spaces. Are you getting what I am trying to say ?